# How to correctly register a Component Section with the Shopware 6 Admin SDK

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

With the Shopware 6 Admin SDK it's possible to add [Component Sections](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/ui/component-section) to the Shopware Admin from an external app via iFrame. However, by following the documentation there is are some issues one might tackle along the way.

The component section iFrame is called something like this:

`http://localhost:3000/?location-id=my-awesome-app-card-before`

1. How can I handle the missing params to properly authenticate this GET request? My app server currently does not allow any requests which cannot authenticate themselves with the usual query params, like shop-id, signature, and so on...
2. I know, that the base-app-url which is previously called already authenticates the component section, however, since those are two different iFrames I don't know how to communicate between them. Also, the VueX State cannot be shared between those two, which also makes it hard in a component section to react to the user language which is usually transferred via the query params.

How can I handle these issues?

**Solution**

Avoid using the home route of your app server (http://localhost:3000) as the entry point of your app in the `<base-app-url>`. With http://localhost:3000/entry or something similar it works fine and the query params are added as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When the iframe is rendered there should be an XHR request `/api/_action/extension-sdk/sign-uri` which should [sign the iframe source URL,](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.20.0/src/Administration/Controller/AdminExtensionApiController.php#L107) meaning it should add all those query parameters necessary for authentication. You can find the corresponding code in the [`QuerySigner`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.20.0/src/Core/Framework/App/Hmac/QuerySigner.php#L39), where there are also language related parameters added in addition to those related to authentication.

On the administration side this call should be initiated by using the [`sw-iframe-renderer`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.20.0/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/extension-api/sw-iframe-renderer/index.ts) component that is used for the `base-app-url`, as well as in [`sw-extension-component-section`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.20.0/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/extension-api/sw-extension-component-section/sw-extension-component-section.html.twig). That's what's making me wonder why in the one instance the url is signed correctly and is missing some parameters in the other one.

Looking at the template of `sw-iframe-renderer` it's only using the signed URL if the computed property `extensionIsApp` is truthy.

```js
extensionIsApp(): boolean {
    return this.extension?.type === 'app';
},
```

and `extension` is another computed property that may return `undefined`.

```js
extension(): Extension | undefined {
    const extensions = Shopware.State.get('extensions');

    return Object.values(extensions).find((ext) => {
        return ext.baseUrl === this.src;
    });
},
```

So the base url of the app apparently differs from the iframe source when it should be the same. Did you change the base url at some point? Try re-installing the app. Verify that the url of both the hidden `base-app-url` iframe and the component section iframe match minus the query parameters.

Comment: So I took a closer look at the App Example from @jleifeld https://github.com/shopware/admin-extension-sdk-example-app. Here he uses ```http://localhost:3000/index.html``` as an entry point for the ```base-app-url```. Thus I changed mine from ```http://localhost:3000``` to ```http://localhost:3000/entry```. This apparently did the trick and the params are added again. There seems to be an issue with the ```base-app-url``` being the home route, I guess.